# Will correlation impact feature importance of ML models?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, feature-selection

I am building a xgboost model with hundreds of features. For features that highly correlated(pearson correlation) with each other, I am thinking to use feature importance(measuring by Gain) to drop the one with low importance.
My question: 
1: Will correlation impact/biase feature importance (measuring by Gain)? 
2: Is there any good way to remove highly correlated feature for ML models?

example: a's importance=120, b's importance=14, corr(a,b)=0.8. I am thinking to drop b because its importance=14. But is it correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Correlation definitely impacts feature importance. Meaning that if the features are highly correlated, there would be a high level of redundancy if you keep them all. Because two features are correlated means change in one will change the another. So there is no need to keep all of them right? As they are surely representative of one another and using a few of them you can hopefully classify your data well.

So in order to remove highly correlated features you can:

1. Use PCA to reduce dimensionality, or,
2. Use decision tree to find the important features, or,
3. You may manually choose features from your knowledge (if it is
   possible) which features are more promising to help you to classify
   your data, or,
4. You can combine some features to a new feature manually such that
   saying one feature may eliminate the necessity to tell another set
   of features as those are likely can be inferred from that single
   feature.

Comment: Use decision tree to find the important features---that is my question, if I use tree model (eg, xgboost) to get feature importance: eg a_importance=120, b_importance=14, corr(a,b)=0.8. I am thinking to drop b because its importance=14. But is it correct? will correlation bias feature importance of individual feature?

Comment: @jean I never worked with xgboost but I think it should be correct. As high correlation makes the features representative to one another so correlation reduces the feature importance of individual features. You should make an experiment it to see the difference. This might be helpful:  http://rnowling.github.io/machine/learning/2015/08/11/random-forest-correlation-bias.html